# Combining multiple rows values into single

Tags: mysql, sql

There are few rows:

```
Id marks 
1  15   
1  16
1  17  
2  6
2  15
3  9
3  10
```

I want to merge all the id into a single row, with
output like below:

```
 Id  marks1 marks2 marks3 
 1   15    16      17
 2   6     15
 3   9     10
```

Comment: Add some more sample data, e.g. (2,15), (2,16) and (3,18), and adjust the expected result.

Comment: How did you get on @Ritesh Sharma?

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating fields into a single field is made really easy in mysql. there is function for it. `CONCAT()`. Better yet if you and want to delimit them by the same string you can use `CONCAT_WS()`. which is concatenate with separator, the first parameter being the separator and any other argument after being a field you wish to join.

> http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(' ', marks1, marks2, marks3) as 'mark1 | mark2 | mark3' from my_table group by id;
```

**UPDATE**

I think I Misunderstood your schema structure. I think what you actually are looking for is `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

> http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(marks) as 'All Marks' from my_table group by id;
```